# How can I get Pymacs to work in Ubuntu with EPD python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, enthought

EPD python does not know to look for the Ubuntu repository python so installing Pymacs through Ubuntu does not help. The alternative is to clone into the [Pymacs source from github] and manually install it[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/852287).

A clean way of doing this is to use `python setup.py install --user`, and you'd want to change that in the Makefile, but this doesn't work!  I tried this, and it did not provide the Pymacs module for the native python or EPD.  You can read about the problems with this [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/852287) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/852293).

In order to use the Pymacs from the Ubuntu repo, I tried putting `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` in my ~/.bashrc, but that caused a lot of the EPD stuff to be over-ridden by native python stuff because this path gets added to sys.path in front of the EPD initial path.  If I manually add this path using sys.path.append when I run ipython, that works, but it's a hassle.

I also tried putting `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pymacs` in my ~/.bashrc, but for some reason, that did not make the Pymacs module available to EPD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a workaround that seems to do well.  After having installed rope, ropemode, and ropemacs using `python setup.py install --user`, I ran the command `ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pymacs ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pymacs`.  For some reason, EPD apparently scans this directory at startup to know that is has access to the Pymacs module.  I don't know why adding the target directory to my PYTHONPATH did not and this did, but that's what happened.  If anyone has a better way, please let me know.